# what could be the reason for my java UI unit test grabbing focus on GNOME desktop

Tags: java, linux

I am running a UI unit test with multiple scenarios that requires the UI to get focus when it starts. This test runs for a while and I am facing an issue in GNOME desktop where the focus goes back to this application for each scenario it executes; this prevents me from using my machine when this test case running.

This works fine on windows and linux with KDE environments.

Any indicators on why this could be happening on GNOME desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the focus, but you can run it on a different display, using `Xvfb` or something similar to stop it from using your current screen.

Alternatively, refactor your classes to not be so intimate with the GUI ( see [the humble object](http://xunitpatterns.com/Humble%20Object.html) ).